# (22)Invalid argument: FastCGI: process manager exiting, setgid() failed

Tags: apache, cgi, fastcgi

I am trying to start the Apache server and I am going to use Fast CGI.
When I try to start it, I get following error message in error_log.

> [alert] (22)Invalid argument: FastCGI: process manager exiting, setgid(4294967295) failed

So it looks like it is setting the group id and at that time it gave this alert message.

Any idea about this alert message?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the group you have configured Apache to run under (often www-data) doesn't exist. Can you verify what group Apache is running as and that the group exists on your system?

This link might help you: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ.html#setgid